# spring boot - r2dbc - webflux - postgre - bad SQL grammar

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I started (with spring initializer) a simple Reactive (non-blocking) app...
But whenever try to make any query to postgres db always end up with: "org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarException: executeMany; bad SQL grammar (...)"

Repo:

```
public interface VolunteerRepo extends R2dbcRepository<Volunteer, Long> {
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final VolunteerService volunteerService;

    public UserController(VolunteerService volunteerService) {
        this.volunteerService = volunteerService;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class VolunteerService {
    private final VolunteerRepo volunteerRepo;
    
    public VolunteerService(VolunteerRepo volunteerRepo) {
        this.volunteerRepo = volunteerRepo;
    }

    public Flux<Volunteer> getAllVlounteers() {
        return volunteerRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

I do connect do db by:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WolontariuszeApplication {
    @Bean
    ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql")));

        return initializer;
    }
//(...)
}
```

and my schema.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Volunteers (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    username VARCHAR(255), 
    password VARCHAR(255), 
    role VARCHAR(255), 
    active BOOLEAN, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

When I am creating a custome query in repo '@Query()' it is working... but it is far from properly using build in methods in repo interface...

Answer (score 0):

So... I figured out that I have created a table name 'VOLUNTEERS' instead of my class name 'VOLUNTEER' ...